# Javascript delete blobs from xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, video, web-applications, garbage-collection, xmlhttprequest

I have a web app that pre-loads videos by requesting blobs and creating blob urls.

```
// Get video Blob URL
const url = 'https://www.some-video-url.com/video.mp4';
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', sourceUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onprogress = () => {console.log('downloading')};
const blobUrl;
xhr.onload = () => {
  blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(req.response);
  console.log('done');
};
xhr.send();
...


// After using video
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
```

I would send such requests multiple times. It work fine in the beginning, however, when I send too many of these requests I get this error.

```
VM1853:10 GET https://www.some-video-url.com/video.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

I am running this on Chrome and it here is my hypothesis.

According to this [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/storage/browser/blob/README.md) it seems like Blob storage limit for chrome is 10% of total disk space. I confirmed this by sending xhr request to GET a 2 GB file until I hit the error. It got an error when I sent request for 20 of the 2GB files. It seems like the blobs are not garbage collected because it is not properly de-referenced. This mysterious reference seems to be related to the xhr.

In my application, I would like to 
1. Start downloading videos in the background
2. Client watches a video
3. When the video playback is done, remove the video

Is there a reliable way to execute step 3? I would like the Blob to be deleted after its use.

Comment: you tried doing any analysis using the chrome dev tools? Check out the memory tab, maybe try taking some snapshots. It won't help solve your problem but it could help confirm/deny your hypothesis.

Comment: I am somewhat confident that blobs are being stored in a temp directory. I see the Blobs in this directory
/usr/local/home/${USER}/.config/google-chrome/Default/blob_storage/